# PHP regex to find special group of string in tẽt

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like:

```
$string = 'hay qua nhi @[3818||Vinh HandSome] và @[101623||Vũ Hoài Anh] ';
```

I want to convert it into an array:

```
$array  = array([0]=>'@[3818||Vinh HandSome]',[1]=>'@[101623||Vũ Hoài Anh]');
```

and also want to replace the original string with:

```
$string  = 'hay qua nhi <a href='users/3818'>Vinh HandSome</a> và <a href='users/101623'>Vũ Hoài Anh</a>';
```

So I tried to use regex:

```
echo preg_replace("/@\[([0-9]+)\|\|(.*)\]/","<a href='/users/$1'>$2</a>",$string);
preg_match_all("/@\[([0-9]+)\|\|(.*)\]/", $string, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($result[0]);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have an idea about correct regular expression for this case?

Comment: Excuse me, placed it in the wrong thread. May be removed.

Comment: I sometimes suffer with regex too - but try and plug it into this site, it tends to help me with cases like these: http://txt2re.com

Comment: Hi @KaviSiegel i go to this site but this abit not easy to work with, can you tell me a example like this case apply there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a lazy operator for both regular expressions: `/@\[([0-9].+?)\|\|(.+?)\]/`

Comment: hi Skidrow, your solution work but missing escape i guess because this can not post in comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = 'hay qua nhi @[3818||Vinh HandSome] và @[101623||Vũ Hoài Anh] ';
$pattern = '/@\[([\d]+)\|\|([^\]]+)\]/';
$replacement = "<a href='users/$1'>$2</a>";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Now, `$result` will contain

```
hay qua nhi <a href='users/3818'>Vinh HandSome</a> và <a href='users/101623'>Vũ Hoài Anh</a>
```